# How to charge a Sony PS3 wireless keypad with a PC?

Tags: ps3

I can charge the PS3 controller with a standard USB port of a PC. But I can not charge the [PS3 wireless **keypad**](http://us.playstation.com/ps3/accessories/wireless-keypad-ps3.html). When I connect it to the PC, I get the error, that a driver is missing. I do not want to use is with a PC. I just want to charge it. Do I need the driver to charge it? Or what else do I need to do to charge it with a PC?

Comment: drivers are not required for charging. If its connected, and its not powering, it can not charge that way.

Comment: I'm guessing it thinks you want to use it, but is likely charging anyway. Ignore the error and see if it charges.

Comment: @DangerZone The controller is blinking, if it is charging. And my one does not blink, if I connect it to the PC.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you charge the PS3 wireless controller over regular USB?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10118/can-you-charge-the-ps3-wireless-controller-over-regular-usb)

Comment: @Nelson: Unless I'm very much mistaken, this question says "I _can_ charge a PS3 wireless controller, how can I charge _this other device_?".

Comment: @Nelson **not a duplicate**, this is asking about keypad, the question you linked is about the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled with this too. I had to install 3rd party drivers but I was also looking to use it on PC emulating a 360 controller. I used DS3 but there are probably other ones out there. Keep in mind you can't use it with the PS3 if it's charging.. I ended up just getting a 15 foot usb to mini b cord for like 10 bucks on amazon.

It's one of the few things I hate about the PS3.

Comment: Which driver did you install?

Comment: DS3 tool's should work, but I hate it with a passion. Last time I used (couple years back) you had to be online so that it could serve you ads on it's program, and it wouldn't work offline. There's a 'betterds3' out there that's supposed to be a better version, but I could never get it to work.